# Problem with querying in Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Hi i have a python script that connects to an Amazon RDS machine and check for new entries.
my scripts works on the localhost perfectly. But on the RDS it does not detect the new entry. once i cancel the script and run again i get the new entry. For testing i tried it out like this

```
cont = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","DB") 
cursor = cont.cursor() 
for i in range(0, 100):
    cursor.execute("Select count(*) from box")
    A = cursor.fetchone()
    print A
```

and during this process when i add a new entry it does not detect the new entry but when i close the connection and run it again i get the new entry. Why is this i checked the cache it was at 0. what else am i missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this, it is due to the Isolation level in Mysql, all i had to do was

```
Set the default transaction isolation level transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
```

And i am using Django for this i had to add this in the django database settings

```
'OPTIONS': {
                "init_command": "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED"
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen in MySQL command-line clients as well.

My understanding (from other people linking to this URL) is that Python's API often silently creates transactions: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

If that is true, then your cursor is looking at a consistent version of the data, even after another transaction adds rows.  You could try doing a `cursor.rollback()` in the `for` loop to stop the implicit transaction that the `SELECT` is running in.